# Are there any JavaScript minifiers that preserve line breaks?

Tags: javascript, minify

Error reporting from the client that always reports an error on line 1 (because the file is minified) is not very useful. I'd like to minify my code while preserving line breaks so that I get meaningful line numbers.

Are there any JavaScript [minifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) that have an option to preserve line breaks?

Comment: Are you able to share the JS you're trying to minify?

Comment: My deployement scripts usually deploy both the minified version and the non minified version (not accessible at the same address) so that I never never have to debug the minified one. You should do the same, there is no reason to try to debug a minified code.

Comment: This is for code that is running in a production environment. These errors are also being reported from user's browsers so I don't have the ability to debug it when it happens. But knowing which line the error happened on will help me find the error back in my dev environment.

Comment: Probably you should not be using a minified version of your script for debugging?

Comment: I am not debugging using the minified version. This if for errors that happen on a user's machine. They are using the minified version. When an error happens on their machine I do not want to get a report saying the error happened on line 1 (because the file was minfied into 1 line). I want the user to get a minified file that preserves line breaks that way when I get the error report it says something like line 345. Which I can then easily look up to see what code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) from Google with the pretty print option enabled.

There are also plenty of options if you use the command line tool.

Comment: From the documentation the pretty_print formatting option will add line breaks and indentation. Preferably it would remove all whitespace except the line breaks. That way the lines map one to one to the original source. If the compiler is adding line breaks where it sees fit it won't map one to one.

Comment: Well this way still works pretty well for finding the offending code even if it doesn't map one to one to the original source. So I think I will go with this solution for now. Maybe I will find a minifier that preserves newlines exactly in the future. Thanks Fabien.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for the same thing and although I've not found exactly what I want, I've just seen that the (now deprecated) [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor/) has a `--line-break 0` switch that causes a line break to be inserted after each semicolon.  Since I was using YUI Compressor anyway, I think this will do for my debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In the years since this question was originally asked, *all* major minifiers, transpilers, bundlers, and debugging tools have gained support for [source maps](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/how_to/use_a_source_map/index.html).

These let debuggers map exceptions from transformed code to the right place in the original source code and renders approaches like preserving new lines unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Babel had this option for a long time.

https://babeljs.io/docs/options#retainlines

Answer (score -1):

I think this is it:
https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/inspector

As Fabien said, closure compiler ... but after looking for this for the third time, I found out that the closure compiler can produce a mapping file between optimized code and original source :)

You also are not limited to using the web service; you can download it as a stand-alone application :)

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

It is a win-win.

Comment: The first link is broken (404).