# ASP.NET MVC bundling and minifying without removing new line characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle, minify

Using ASP.NET MVC bundling, is it possible to have minified files where the new line characters are not removed?

I was looking into JsMinify class, but cannot figure out if that is possible to configure.

I want to keep the new line characters for javascript error handling. I am setting up an javascript autotamed error reporting from client side and I would like to see on which line did the error occur.

Comment: Without removing a newline character it is not a [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)

Comment: I agree with Murali. One solution for "production" debugging (I can't advise that though) would be to have both minified and orignal file deployed and use a querystring (like ?DebugJS=True) to tell your application to load the full version of the file. This way you do not lose minification ratio and you can still debug if needed.

Comment: Is it not? I would still benefit from decreased payload, because of removed white-space chars and shortened variable names. But at the same time I could know exactly at which line of code to look in case of errors.

Comment: The purpose is not debbuging production code. I am setting up a client side error reporting, and I would benefit greatly if the error report could point out the line of code where the error occured.

Comment: Oh, then you should add that to the description of your question. By error handling I didn't get that (thought it was "human" error handling).

Comment: I have clarified my question. Thanks for suggestion, @cahmadzadeh.

Comment: You could have a look at the following website: http://refresh-sf.com/yui/. It allows adding a linebreak after a specified column number plus different other options. It is based on YUI, so maybe this API might help you.

Comment: This question might be useful, and may even be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854507/are-there-any-javascript-minifiers-that-preserve-line-breaks